# Must declare the scalar variable "@query" dynamic tsql to stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've read somewhere that it's impossible to create stored procedure from dynamic query.

I have some error that I didn't declare scalar variable.

Here is my tsql dynamic report which is working:

```
 DECLARE 
 @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @selcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @startdate datetime,
 @enddate datetime,
 @paramdef nvarchar(max)

 SET @startdate = '2013-02-01'
 SET @enddate = '2013-05-10';
 SET @paramdef = '@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime';


 SELECT 
@selcols = STUFF((SELECT ','+'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) + ', 0) AS ' +  QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
               FROM AdeccoView
               --where datein > @startdate
               --    and datein <= @enddate
               GROUP BY [Date]
               ORDER BY [Date]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


  SELECT 
 @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
               FROM AdeccoView
               --where datein > @startdate
               --    and datein <= @enddate
               GROUP BY [Date]
               ORDER BY [Date]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

 SET @query = N'SELECT CreatedBy,Name, Surname,EventTypeID,Event, '+ @selcols + ',Total
    from 
    (
        select av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy,emp.Name,emp.Surname,Event,
            convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120) [Date],
            row_number() over(PARTITION BY [date],av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy  order BY av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy ) m,
            count(*) over(partition by av.CreatedBy,av.EventTypeId) Total
        from AdeccoView av
        left join EventType et on et.EventTypeID = av.EventTypeID
        left join Employee emp on av.CreatedBy = emp.EmployeeD

    ) x
    pivot 
    (
        max(m)
        for [Date] in ('+@cols+')
    ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query, @paramdef, @startdate = @startdate, @enddate =@enddate;
```

And now,

I want it through stored procedure or a View (maybe is easier later on to implement in entity framework 6, asp.net). So my stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetEmployees
( @startDateInput datetime = NULL, @endDateInput datetime = NULL) 
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

DECLARE 
@cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@selcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@startdate datetime,
@enddate datetime,
@paramdef nvarchar(max)

SET @startdate = @startDateInput
SET @enddate = @endDateInput
SET @paramdef = '@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime';


SELECT 
@selcols = STUFF((SELECT ','+'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) + ', 0) AS ' +  QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
               FROM AdeccoView
               --where datein > @startdate
               --    and datein <= @enddate
               GROUP BY [Date]
               ORDER BY [Date]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


SELECT 
@cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
               FROM AdeccoView
               --where datein > @startdate
               --    and datein <= @enddate
               GROUP BY [Date]
               ORDER BY [Date]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = N'SELECT CreatedBy,Name, Surname,EventTypeID,Event, '+ @selcols + ',Total
    from 
    (
        select av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy,emp.Name,emp.Surname,Event,
            convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120) [Date],
            row_number() over(PARTITION BY [date],av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy order BY av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy ) m,
            count(*) over(partition by av.CreatedBy,av.EventTypeId) Total
        from AdeccoView av
        left join EventType et on et.EventTypeID = av.EventTypeID
        left join Employee emp on av.CreatedBy = emp.EmployeeD

    ) x
    pivot 
    (
        max(m)
        for [Date] in ('+@cols+')
    ) p '
    GO
exec sp_executesql @query, @paramdef, @startdate = @startDateInput, @enddate =@EndDateInput;
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my updated code with BEGIN and END, removed GO statement

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetEmployees
( @startDateInput datetime = NULL, @endDateInput datetime = NULL) 
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
BEGIN
DECLARE 
@cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@selcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@startdate datetime,
@enddate datetime,
@paramdef nvarchar(max)

SET @startdate = @startDateInput
SET @enddate = @endDateInput
SET @paramdef = '@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime';


SELECT 
@selcols = STUFF((SELECT ','+'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) + ', 0) AS ' +  QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
               FROM AdeccoView
               --where datein > @startdate
               --    and datein <= @enddate
               GROUP BY [Date]
               ORDER BY [Date]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


SELECT 
@cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
               FROM AdeccoView
               --where datein > @startdate
               --    and datein <= @enddate
               GROUP BY [Date]
               ORDER BY [Date]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = N'SELECT CreatedBy,Name, Surname,EventTypeID,Event, '+ @selcols + ',Total
    from 
    (
        select av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy,emp.Name,emp.Surname,Event,
            convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120) [Date],
            row_number() over(PARTITION BY [date],av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy  order BY av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy ) m,
            count(*) over(partition by av.CreatedBy,av.EventTypeId) Total
        from AdeccoView av
        left join EventType et on et.EventTypeID = av.EventTypeID
        left join Employee emp on av.CreatedBy = emp.EmployeeD

    ) x
    pivot 
    (
        max(m)
        for [Date] in ('+@cols+')
    ) p '
END

exec sp_executesql @query, @paramdef, @startdate = @startDateInput, @enddate =@EndDateInput;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GO` before the `sp_executesql` finishes the stored procedure declaration.  Hence the variables declared in the stored procedure are not available.  In other words, the code defines the stored procedure.  Then it attempts to run:

```
exec sp_executesql @query, @paramdef, @startdate = @startDateInput, @enddate =@EndDateInput;
```

Note surprisingly, none of the variables are defined because they are local to the stored procedure.

You should not only remove the `GO` but use `BEGIN` and `END` to define the body of the stored procedure.

Comment: Please find attached my edited code. Do you think is OK now? Stored procedure is completed successfully. I think that your answer is solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Stefan0309 . . . Your code looks quite reasonable (although I think the body should be indented).